# Producing word clouds from pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, word-cloud

I have a dataframe with three columns 1.Word, 2.Frequency,3.Category and now I want a world clouds for the unigram words that I have in Word column and I need to assign it frequency as its size using frequency column and I want the color that word based on its category

Comment: You can use [`matplotlib.pyplot.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) with parameters `s` for frequency and `c` for colour. Or take inspiration from this: [Packed-bubble chart](https://matplotlib.org/3.4.1/gallery/misc/packed_bubbles.html)

Comment: @Stef I this OP want a [word cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_cloud) ;)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this format of input:

```
    word  frequency category
0   this        0.3     long
1     is        0.1    short
2      a        0.1     long
3  quick        0.2    short
4   test        0.3     long
```

you could use:

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# dictionary to map colors
colors = {'short': 'red', 'long': 'blue'}
# color mapping function
def colors_func(word=None, **kwargs):
    return df.set_index('word')['category'].map(colors).get(word)

# create word cloud
wc = WordCloud(background_color='white', color_func=colors_func)
wc.generate_from_frequencies(df.set_index('word')['frequency'])

# plot
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(wc, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

example output:

[image]